# check double list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I have a predicate called `check(A,B)`. that checks if list A matches with another list B.

I need to make a predicate that checks if a list's elements are single lists.

Comment: Show us the code you have this far.

Comment: Also your question is very hard to understand. What do you mean by single lists? [[a], [b], [c]] ?

Comment: i mean cheak(A,B) can work in a single list like L=[1,2,3,4] . I want to make it work for a list like L=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]

Comment: which implementation of prolog are you using ?

Comment: the check predicate is mine but i can't make it work for a list like this L=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]]
It would be usefull to gine my code?

Comment: Why doesn't your `check` work those more complicated lists? What exactly is the predicate you want to create supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
checkList([],[]).
checkList([A|A2],[B|B2]) :- check(A,B), checkList(A2,B2).
```

This assumes that if A & B aren't "single lists", then check will fail (which sounds like what you want).

Answer (score 0):

Why couldn't you just use

```
check(A,B) :- A=B.
```

Then it wouldn't matter what kinds of elements the lists were made up of; heck, they wouldn't haven to be lists at all!

Comment: i don't want to check if the 2 lists are the same , i want to see if two lists match according to some calculations . I have created the predicate to chek for two ordinary lists . I need now to make it for lists in list.